# Embedded mqtt in Home Assistant working fine until JS test

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I have Home Assistant installed and i have some ESP-module that can connect to wi-fi and MQTT server (which is embedded in HA on port 1883). Here some code from configuration.yaml:

```
mqtt:
    username: "homeassistant"
    password: ""
light:
  - platform: mqtt_json
    name: mqtt_json_light_2
    state_topic: "home/rgb1"
    command_topic: "home/rgb1/set"
    brightness: true
    rgb: true
    effect: true
    effect_list: [colorfade_slow, colorfade_fast, flash]
    optimistic: false
    qos: 0
```

Everything working fine, connection to MQTT (192.168.43.184:1883) with username and password is fine.

After that i create page for testing on this server using paho-mqtt.js. I can run this page with http://192.168.43.184:8123/local/index.html. So.. same server but not https, so mb thats the main reason of no connection on this page.

simple code for test:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
      <script src="js/paho-mqtt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //sample HTML/JS script that will publish/subscribe to topics in the Google Chrome Console
        //by Matthew Bordignon @bordignon on twitter.
        var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";  //mqtt websocket enabled brokers
        var wsport = 1883; // or for above
        var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
            "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
        client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
          console.log("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
        };
        client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
          console.log(message.destinationName, ' -- ', message.payloadString);
        };
        var options = {
          timeout: 3,
          userName: "homeassistant",
          password: "",
          onSuccess: function () {
            console.log("mqtt connected");
          },
          onFailure: function (message) {
            console.log("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
          }
        };
      function init() {
          client.connect(options);
      }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init();">
      </body>
    </html>
```

Page is running on HA server so adress can be localhost or 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.43.184 - non of this working and i have only this:

> Connection failed: AMQJSC0001E Connect timed out.

But i can connect end listen with my ESP/rasberi etc. I can even send messages with http://192.168.43.184:8123/dev-mqtt.
My js is not rigth or something?

Comment: Now connection is fine (8080 port solve the problem)
But when i try to send a message - i get error and lost connect:
"AMQJS0005E Internal error. Error Message: undefined"
It means my JSON is bad but i copied this one from dev-mqtt page of Home Assistant so its fine. I dont know why i cant send message to MQTT via js now.